# Yii Translation Array : How to get a specific value within a nested array

Tags: php, yii

I am trying to get a specific value from Yii Translation Array;

This array should work fine if I use it like a `key` -> `value`;

But when I want to translate the year months, I need a nested array within the translation array;

How can I get a value within the `months` array?

Is it possible?

`Yii::t('key','value');` is the way the translation is used, where `key` is the name of the file and `value` is the `key` within the array returned, so `key` might be `currency` or `months` in this case

```
return array(
'currency' => 'euro',
'months' => array(
        1 => 'Ianuarie',
        2 => 'Februarie',
        3 => 'Martie',
        4 => 'Aprilie',
        5 => 'Mai',
        6 => 'Iunie',
        7 => 'Iulie',
        8 => 'August',
        9 => 'Septembrie',
        10 => 'Octombrie',
        11 => 'Noiembrie',
        12 => 'Decembrie'
    ),
);
```

Comment: the easyest way is to create a new file and not use a nested array; but  how do I extract a value when using a nested array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how the Yii CPhpMessageSource translation works. You are not able to do it that way.

> **CPhpMessageSource**: the message translations are stored as **key-value pairs** in a **single** PHP array. The original message is the key and the translated message is the value. Each array represents the translations for a particular category of messages and is stored in a separate PHP script file whose name is the category name. The PHP translation files for the same language are stored under the same directory named as the locale ID. And all these directories are located under the directory specified by basePath.